# AppActivate doesn't always activate the application window

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, automation, focus

So I'm working on some VBScript that will automate Internet Explorer: Open it, navigate, and download a file. I've got it working, however there's an issue that lies with the fact that I need to send keystrokes to it. `SendKeys` is working for me, but the problem is that when I use `AppActivate` to set focus on IE, it doesn't always work. Basically it can fall into these two cases:

**Case 1**: Double-click my .vbs file and the automation process goes smoothly. Window is activated and everything works fine.

**Case 2**: Double-click my .vbs file and some other app opens a window that steals focus (or manually click something else to change focus). When the `AppActivate` line is executed later on, IE never gets focused and the keystrokes obviously don't go through.

So do you guys have any ideas on why `AppActivate` isn't setting focus?

Here's the code I'm using to activate the IE window:

```
Do While Not wshell.AppActivate("Active Agents - Internet Explorer")
    WScript.Sleep(1)
Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

This script example of running IE and send keys with AppActivate focus

```
    'fuction to set the application active and then send keys 
    Function mySendKey(sKey,sTime)
       for i=0 to 600        ' this loop will continue about 30 sec if this not enough increase this number
        'get the window title of the IE
        title= sh.Exec("cmd.exe /c tasklist /v /fi ""imagename EQ iexplore*"" /FO LIST | FIND /i ""window title:"" ").stdOut.readline
        title= Mid (title,15,len(title)-14)
        sh.Popup  title,1

        Sh.AppActivate title
        Rtn=Sh.AppActivate(title)     '  window title of application
        If Rtn = True  Then           'if the window active then execute sned keys
            Sh.SendKeys  sKey                                     
            Exit For 
        End If
        wscript.sleep 10                              
      Next
     WScript.Sleep sTime*1000
    End Function

  'hide the cmd window from popup 
  If StrComp(right(WScript.FullName,11),"wscript.exe",1) = 0 Then    
  WScript.Quit CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("cscript.exe //nologo """ & WScript.ScriptFullName & """", 0, False)
  End If 
  'open internet explorer   
Set Sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Sh.Exec "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
WScript.Sleep 7000
 'call mySendKey function to send keys to IE  
 Call mySendKey("(% )(x)",1)                         'max the windows of IE
 Call mySendKey("({F6})(www.yahoo.com)    (~)",10)   'browse to yahoo and wait 10 sec to load
 Call mySendKey("({F6})(www.msn.com)      (~)",10)   'browse to msn and wait 10 sec to load 
 Call mySendKey("(% )(C)",1)                         'close the IE
```